# Serving a S3 bucket and an API Gateway through CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

I want to serve the front end of a web app from a S3 bucket at this url: `www.acme.com`.

At the same time, I want the backend be served from an API Gateway stage (lambda functions are running behind) at this url: `www.acme.com/api` (I don't a `api.acme.com` url to avoid having to deal with a broken Same Origin policy).

At this time, I could set up Cloudfront to serve the S3 bucket or the API Gateway stage but not together.

I tried to declare both as resources (first the bucket and then the API Gateway) and two paths in behavior (the default path to the bucket and a second /api to the Gateway). The bucket is served well but a GET to `www.acme.com/api/users` leads to:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Thanks for all clue about how I could resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you configured the origin in CloudFront to forward all necessary headers to the API Gateway origin?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders ... speculating, you should probably *not* configure CloudFront to forward the `Host` header.

Comment: I tried both: setting in Behaviors the Forward Headers field to All and also to None. Nothing worked, Michael.

Comment: I'm jazzed about the [new back-end security mechanism they recently rolled out on API Gateway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32678649/1695906) so I was hoping to play with it some this weekend, anyway.  While at it, I'll see if I can try to replicate your setup and see what I come up with.  What does your API-GW use for access control/auth?  API token? IAM? Public/none? Something else? Does it expect certain headers?

Comment: Oh... You didn't set the [origin path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath) in CloudFront, did you?  If you did, that might be wrong.  If you set it to `/api` then your request would be forwarded as `/api/api/users` and this message, while obscure, could be expected. Not to be confused with [path pattern](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern), which of course you would need.

Comment: The API-GW is public. I tried both, setting and not setting the origin path. I also tried with both path patterns /dev/* and dev/* (without slash). The only way I could use cloudFront in front of API GW is directly, as default behavior. Look: https://d2xj67tzdts77c.cloudfront.net/users/list

Comment: But wait, though... there's no `/dev/` in `/users/list`.  What path on the api does this CF request actually hit?

Comment: Speculating: your api expects /users/list but you are putting /api or some other prefix in CloudFront?  That won't work.  CloudFront can't remove path components, or modify them; it can only prepend them.  Your api needs to expect the whole path, e.g. /api/dev/users/list is what the API gateway has to be expecting, if that's the path you're hitting CloudFront with in the request.

Comment: Michael, I didn't saw your comment until now but you were on the right path (unlike me ;) )!

Answer (score 6):

My fault: I've set the Origin Path to `/api` in Origin and the Path Pattern to `api/*` in Behavior. I don't know why but I made the assumption the setting `api/*` in Behavior would cut "api/" in the url path. Indeed, with this set up, CF was routing to an inexistent url (`/api/api/...`) inside API GW.

That's why I got a: `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`.

Conclusion: if you use more than one stage in your Gateway, the stage  will be the base of the path of your url and you should not leave the Origin Path blank.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question regarding the charging of such a setup: are you getting charged twice for bandwidth and requests by CloudFront and APIGW or is it just the API Gateway cost?